# Camera with "track to" constraint flips

Tags: camera, constraints

I have a "track to" constraint and a "follow path" constraint applied to my camera. When the offset of the "track to" reaches a certain point, the camera flips around 180°. Is there a way to avoid this? In the file I already animated the camera to reproduce the behavior. thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the *Follow CUrve* option of your *Follow Path* constraint, disable the *Track To*, give a *Damped Track* instead, on -Z:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Turn on target Z

[image]

Rotate empty in x-axis so that Z-axis is pointed in up direction of the camera:

[image]

Animate it:

[image]